# Publishing in multidisciplinary open access journals in computer sciences

Tags: journals, computer-science, open-access, multidisciplinary

My this question is specific to Computer Science discipline(or, Engineering discipline can also be included).

- What about publishing articles, from computer science domain, in multidisciplinary open access journals?

The reason for asking this question is that I had seen on some blog that researchers do not give much credit to such articles (from computer science domain) which are published in open access journals especially in multidisciplinary journals. Some researchers have quoted that don't spoil your CV by publishing in these journals and in research community such articles do not have much respect.

Comment: _What would be the reputation of the articles, from computer science discipline, published in these journals._ — That depends on the article.  Obviously.

Comment: @JeffE Sure, but that does not mean that you will not have at least some sort of initial impression of the probable strength of the paper based on where it is published (even if this might just be some fairly broad range). If I saw someone in math with many publications in PLoS One it would certainly give me a weird initial impression.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sure, I have implicit biases like everyone else, but I try to ignore them. (A mathematician wearing a three-piece suit with a velvet cravat and a spider brooch everywhere would certainly give me a weird initial impression.)

Comment: I have changed the question as previous one does not clarified my point properly.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the reputation of multidisciplinary journals in computer sciences like Plos One and IEEE Access.

It is not possible to comprehend the answer as 'reputation' is undefined.

> Both of these journals have impact factor higher than 3 while IEEE access was started just four years ago. On the other side, it took a long time to get even an impact factor for computer science journals.

This is trivial. Thomson Reuter has to generate the statistics related to the number of articles published, the number of citations, etc. for a long period of time to generate a number called Impact Factor (IF).

> What would be the reputation of the articles, from computer science discipline, published in these journals.

As @JeffE pointed in his comment, it absolutely depends on the article itself. Every article published by a specific journal should not be weighted the same.

> Can we compare the impact factor of these journals with other computer science journal having similar impact factor.

Comparing two different journals based on their impact factors is pointless and inconclusive.

Comment: _It is not possible to comprehend the answer as 'reputation' is undefined._ What's more, neither is 'computer sciences', 'multidisciplinary' or 'journal'. How did OP ever think they would get an answer on that one?

Comment: @sgf Right.. Multidisciplinary in the context of computational biology is far different from computational robotics.

Comment: "It is not possible to comprehend the answer as 'reputation' is undefined." 

What a garbage response. The word "reputation" has a very clear definition in this context and this question is far from being incomprehensible. For instance, I can tell you that IEEE Access is a journal without a particularly high reputation, but it is a few steps above being a predatory journal. An expert in this domain could be more specific.